# Vanilla js fading out instead of fading in

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm linking Bootstrap 5 its just fading out the text instead of fading in.
When I remove the link everything just work fine.

```js
const animatedText = document.querySelector(".fancy");
const strText = animatedText.textContent;

const splitText = strText.split("");

animatedText.textContent = "";
for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
  animatedText.innerHTML += "<animated>" + splitText[i] + "</animated>";
}

let char = 0;
let timer = setInterval(onTick, 50);

function onTick() {
  const animated = animatedText.querySelectorAll('animated')[char];
  animated.classList.add('fade');
  char++
  if (char === splitText.length) {
    complete();
    return;
  }
}

function complete() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
```

```css
animated {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

animated.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="fancy">WELCOME TO MY WORLD</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap have .fade class in CSS which is responsible for "fade out" alert boxes.

Change your "fade" class to "text-fade" or something else and everything will be okay.

Comment: Then accept it by clicking the gray check mark ✅ on the left of the answer.